# Not able to display "Skip Ad" in VAST - FLUID PLAYER

Tags: javascript, json, video-streaming, html5-video, vast

BASE-
I'm working on a **Video Player Project**.
I'm having an **issue with integrating VAST** with it.

I'm **not able to display the SKIP AD button**.

I'm using **FLUID PLAYER**.
LINK TO **DOCUMENTAION - https://docs.fluidplayer.com/docs/configuration/ads/** 
I'm using the following code-

```html
<script src="https://cdn.fluidplayer.com/v3/current/fluidplayer.min.js"></script>
                        <video id="video-id">
                            <source
                                src="https://7yotyu1slxwgqeaj4md7bg-on.drv.tw/TM%20media/TM_Vids/Blacked%20%E2%80%93%20Hot%20Southern%20Blonde%20Takes%20Big%20Black%20Cock%20%E2%80%93%20Cherie%20Deville,%20Prince%20Yahshua.mp4"
                                type="video/mp4" />
                            <script>
                                var myFP = fluidPlayer(
                                    'video-id', {
                                    "layoutControls": {
                                        "controlBar": {
                                            "autoHideTimeout": 3,
                                            "animated": true,
                                            "autoHide": true
                                        },
                                        "htmlOnPauseBlock": {
                                            "html": null,
                                            "height": null,
                                            "width": null
                                        },
                                        "autoPlay": true,
                                        "mute": false,
                                        "allowTheatre": true,
                                        "playPauseAnimation": true,
                                        "playbackRateEnabled": true,
                                        "allowDownload": false,
                                        "playButtonShowing": true,
                                        "fillToContainer": true,
                                        "posterImage": ""
                                    },
                                    "vastOptions": {

                                        "allowVPAID": true, // Default false.
                                        "adList": [
                                            {
                                                "roll": "preRoll",
                                                "vastTag": "https://www.videosprofitnetwork.com/watch.xml?key=0185fa78fd7a7789bf1d0ac524fec3f4",
                                                "adText": ""
                                            },
                                            {
                                                "roll": "midRoll",
                                                "vastTag": "https://www.videosprofitnetwork.com/watch.xml?key=0185fa78fd7a7789bf1d0ac524fec3f4",
                                                "adText": ""
                                            },
                                            {
                                                "roll": "postRoll",
                                                "vastTag": "https://www.videosprofitnetwork.com/watch.xml?key=0185fa78fd7a7789bf1d0ac524fec3f4",
                                                "adText": ""
                                            }
                                        ],
                                        "skipButtonCaption": 'Skip ad in [seconds]',
                                        "skipButtonClickCaption": 'Skip ad <span class="skip_button_icon"></span>',
                                        "adText": null,
                                        "adTextPosition": 'top left',
                                        "adCTAText": 'Visit now!',
                                        "adCTATextPosition": 'bottom right',
                                        "vastTimeout": 5000,
                                        "showPlayButton": false,
                                        // maxAllowedVastTagRedirects: 1,

                                        
                                    }
                                })
                            </script>

                    </div>
                    <!-- end video player -->
```

**SPECIFICALLY THIS JSON-**

```json
"vastOptions": {

                                        "allowVPAID": true, // Default false.
                                        "adList": [
                                            {
                                                "roll": "preRoll",
                                                "vastTag": "https://www.videosprofitnetwork.com/watch.xml?key=0185fa78fd7a7789bf1d0ac524fec3f4",
                                                "adText": ""
                                            },
                                            {
                                                "roll": "midRoll",
                                                "vastTag": "https://www.videosprofitnetwork.com/watch.xml?key=0185fa78fd7a7789bf1d0ac524fec3f4",
                                                "adText": ""
                                            },
                                            {
                                                "roll": "postRoll",
                                                "vastTag": "https://www.videosprofitnetwork.com/watch.xml?key=0185fa78fd7a7789bf1d0ac524fec3f4",
                                                "adText": ""
                                            }
                                        ],
                                        "skipButtonCaption": 'Skip ad in [seconds]',
                                        "skipButtonClickCaption": 'Skip ad <span class="skip_button_icon"></span>',
                                        "adText": null,
                                        "adTextPosition": 'top left',
                                        "adCTAText": 'Visit now!',
                                        "adCTATextPosition": 'bottom right',
                                        "vastTimeout": 5000,
                                        "showPlayButton": false,
                                        // maxAllowedVastTagRedirects: 1,


                                    }
```

Still I'm not getting the Skip Ad Button.
Can someone please help guys?

Comment: Can you share the xmlResponse you are trying to play?
There should be a `skipoffset` attribute in the `Linear` elemnt